# Wildfly 18 throws ModuleNotFoundException after module was added

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, java-11, wildfly-18

I'm deploying Wildfly 18.0.0.Final running on JDK 11 and I can't make recognize a module that I added.

This is the message that I get.

```
2022-09-03 15:51:04,703 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.validator-api-2.41.0.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.validator-api-2.41.0.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.validator-api-2.41.0.war
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind-api
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:299)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:283)
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:93)
    ... 8 more
```

I have added the module using jboss-cli.sh like this.

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect "module add --name=jakarta.xml.bind-api --resources=/tmp/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar --dependencies=jakarta.activation-api"
```

A folder was created at this location.

```
/opt/wildfly/modules/jakarta/xml/bind-api/main/
```

Containing these files.

```
drw-rw-r-- 1 wildfly wildfly   4096 Sep  3 15:01 .
drw-rw-r-- 1 wildfly wildfly   4096 Sep  3 15:01 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wildfly wildfly 127111 Sep  3 14:57 jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wildfly wildfly    300 Sep  3 14:57 module.xml
```

The content of **module.xml** is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="jakarta.xml.bind-api">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="jakarta.activation-api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And in the file **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** I added the module like this.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
      <subsystem name="webservices" />
      <subsystem name="resteasy" />
      <subsystem name="weld" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="javaee.api" />
      <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
      <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" />
      <module name="org.jboss.as.webservices.*" />
      <module name="org.jboss.ws.*" />
    </exclusions>

    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.activation.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.el.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.enterprise.deploy.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.inject.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.resource.api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.rmi.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.security.jacc.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true" />
      
      <!-- <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" export="true" services="export" /> -->

      <!-- <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="jakarta.xml.bind-api" export="true" />
      <!-- <module name="javax.xml.registry.api" export="true" /> -->
      <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" export="true" />
      <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />

      <!-- This one always goes last. -->
      <module name="javax.api" export="true" />
    </dependencies>

  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have tried everything that has come to my mind without any good results.

If needed, this is the structure of my **pom.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.penneo</groupId>
  <artifactId>validator-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.41.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Validator API</name>
  <url>https://penneo.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.jboss.spec.javaee.8.0>1.0.4.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.8.0>

    <version.cucumber>1.2.4</version.cucumber>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>
    <version.jersey>2.36</version.jersey>
    <version.clean.plugin>3.0.0</version.clean.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app
         is deployed -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/app/deployment/</outputDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.clean.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>/app/deployment/</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>${project.artifactId}-*.war*</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-8.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.8.0}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.penneo</groupId>
      <artifactId>validator</artifactId>
      <version>[2.41.0,)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>[2.17.1,)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>[2.17.1,)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
      <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
      <version>${version.jersey}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
      <version>0.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
      <version>0.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have the `jakarta.activation-api` module defined? WildFly does already ship with a `javax.xml.bind.api` module.

Comment: I didn't have it defined so I tried to define it and got the same error but for that module.

org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jakarta.activation-api

Then I download the jar file and add it to the modules as I did with `jakarta.xml.bind-api` and still got the same error with this one.

Finally, I added it to my main pom.xml file, and still got the same error.

So, no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

So I finally was able to this issue.

The solution was to not include the module at all and it seems that I had a misconfiguration in `standalone.xml`.

By solving those two things everything worked fine.